# An error occurred using the connection to database 'main' on server 'C:\ProductDB.db'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have not created a database, but I have written a code for it, if there is no way to create
i have installed my sqlite database but I keep getting the same error what should I do?
i have it in my migrations folder, I'm doing exactly the same as the guy on the course I'm following, but he's giving me errors.

SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "sqlconnection":"Data Source = C:\\ProductDB.db"
  }
}
```

Comment: And  - what is the question here? Someone stole my car, how can I drive it. I have no way to get it back. Program needs the database. You do not have one. You have no way to get it. You cannot run program.

Comment: Try put the database file in other fólder than the root system folder

Answer (score 0):

My working sqlite connectionstring is using `Filename=` not "datasource="

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UTsContext>(options => 

    options.UseSqlite("Filename=E:\\UTs\\UTs.db3"));
```